# Appmaker get all records of a model on serverside

Tags: google-app-maker

Is there an easy way to get all the records of a model at once in a serverside script, or at least all keys ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all records:

```
var allRecords = app.models.MODELNAME.newQuery().run();
```

To get all records keys:

```
var allRecordsKeys = app.models.MODELNAME.newQuery().run().map(function(item){return item._key;});
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/server#querying_records